# D3- Approach for Json nested key-value

Tags: json, d3.js, nested, structure

I would like to have an normal force layout node-link graph so I requested a Json file.
In my Json file, a node:

1. Belong to multiple list
2. Each list, depend on node, have different sub-list

For example:

> Node A belong to List 1 and 2. And with List 1, node A has sublist A* 
>   and B* and with List 2, node A has sublist B*.
>
> Node B belongs  to List 1 also, but can have just sublist A*

It seemed to me that my Json would be as array of an array which requires business logic process.

How should I approach it? What the structure of my Json should be and whether I can use D3 to access it after binding?

Comment: Are the lists and sublists important when you draw the graph (if so, how do you want this represented)? Or do you just need to do a "union" of all lists to get the nodes, and the links are from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a bipartite graph. The easiest is probably to have different arrays, for nodes, lists, "node in list", "sublists of node".

```
{
 nodes = [ {name: "A"}, 
           {name:"B"} ],
 lists = [ {name:"List1"}, 
           {name:"List2"},
           {name:"A*"},
           {name:"B*"} ],
 nodeInList = [ //which node belong to which list? source = index of node, target=index of list 
                {source: 0, target:1}, //A in List1
                {source: 0, target:2}, //B in List1
                 ...
              ],
 sublistInNode = [//which lists are sublists of which nodes? source=index of list, target = index of list
                  {source: 2, target:0}, //A* sublist of A
                  {source: 2, target:1}, //A* sublist of B
                  ...
                 ]
}
```

Now, for a force layout, you need an array of all nodes and an array of all links:

```
allNodes = data.nodes.concat(data.lists)
allLinks = data.nodeInList.concat(data.sublistInNode)
```

You can now use a `d3.force` layout out of the box to represent the list/node relationships.

For styling purpose, you'll probably need to add a "type" field in nodes and links to distinguish whether they are nodes, lists, etc.